# MailMessage cannot assign to Add because it is a method group asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods

I have the following code behind for handling email resulting from a contact form:

```
MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
myMessage.Subject = "Comment from SAM35 website";
myMessage.Body = mailbody;

myMessage.From = new MailAddress("xxxx@yyyy.com", "SAM35 Webamster");
myMessage.To.Add = new MailAddress("xxxx@zzzz.com");
```

This was lifted from a reference book - and it seems reasonable to me.  However, in Visual Studio Express 2015, for the myMessage.To.Add line,  I get the warning message

> Cannot assign to 'Add' because it is a 'method'.

So, having looked around Stack Overflow for similar problems, I tried

```
myMessage.To.Add ("xxxx@zzzz.com");
```

That got rid of the VS warning, but resulted in an unhandled exception when run.  I'd be grateful for a workround on this one.

I changed my code to read

```
MailAddress ToAddress = new MailAddress("aaaaaa@bbbbb", "ccccccc");
        myMessage.To.Add(ToAddress);
        SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        mySmtpClient.Send(myMessage);
```

but still had an exception.

The test is being run locally on localhost, using the aspx file that has the user control embedded, Ctrl+F5 in VS, completing the form details, and hitting the send button.  The unhandled excetption occurs when the run gets as far as

```
  MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
```

Here are details of the excepton:

> System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233033   Message=An invalid character was found in the
>   mail header: '@'.   Source=System   StackTrace:
>          at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ParseLocalPart(String data, Int32& index, Boolean expectAngleBracket, Boolean
>   expectMultipleAddresses)
>          at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ParseAddress(String data, Boolean expectMultipleAddresses, Int32& index)
>          at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ParseAddress(String data)
>          at System.Net.Mail.MailAddress..ctor(String address, String displayName, Encoding displayNameEncoding)
>          at System.Net.Mail.MailMessage..ctor()
>          at Controls_ContactForm.btnSend_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Websites\xxxxWebsite\Controls\ContactForm.ascx.cs:line 21
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   InnerException:

ContactForm.ascx.cs:line 21, which caused the exception, is the line that reads:

```
        MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
```

I don't see why that should have resulted in an '@' in the email header - again advice would be appreciated.

In case it helps, the system.net section of web.config reads:

```
 <system.net>
 <mailSettings>
   <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="yyyyy@gmail.com">
     <network defaultCredentials="false" host="=smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="yyyy@gmail.com" password="qqqqqq"/>
   </smtp>
 </mailSettings>
 </system.net>
```

Comment: We can't help you until you tell us what the unhandled exception is, where it occurred, provide relevant code etc.

Comment: I somehow doubt this was directly _lifted from a reference book_.

Comment: The book is 'Beginning ASP.Net 3.5 by Imar Spaanjaars.  I admit I misread the script.  This project has not been my finest hour.

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassing.  The problem was an error in the web.config file - where through a typo had an email that  managed to have '@' in it two times. Problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add a `MailAddress` object to the `To` object not just a string it is a MailAddressCollection and can have many addresses added.

```
MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
myMessage.Subject = "Comment from SAM35 website";
myMessage.Body = mailbody;

myMessage.From = new MailAddress("xxxx@yyyy.com", "SAM35 Webamster");
MailAddress ToAddress = new MailAddress("xxxx@zzzz.com", "zzz to");
myMessage.To.Add(ToAddress);
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question though.

Comment: Code amended as suggested - but unhandled exception still occurred - as shown in further  details in edited opening post.  I'm baffled.